# Python INSERT won't write to database

Tags: python, mysql

All database names and table names are correct. The python script runs without errors, but the values are never written to the database (table stays empty)`

```
datetimenowDB = str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
deviceDB = "ALARM"
statusDB = "Tripped" 
typeDB = "None"
try:
    db = MySQLdb.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="toor",
    db="log_database")
except Exception as e:
sys.exit('Cant get into database.')

c = db.cursor()

c.execute("INSERT INTO control_log (date_time, device, status, type) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)",
(datetimenowDB, deviceDB, statusDB, typeDB))
```

Answer (score 3):

MySQLdb automatically starts a transaction for you.  You need to call `db.commit()` once you're done making changes.

[See this tutorial](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlpython/).

Comment: Or set `db.autocommit = True`.

Comment: @KevinGuan Technically correct! But transactions are important for performance and, much more importantly, data safety. Turn on autocommit at your peril.